# How to check a condition for every instance method of class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check for an `if condition` whenever an instance method of a class is called.

For example,we have constructor classes that have lots of attributes those are used in payload construct methods but they also have `payload` attribute in which user can pass `payload dictionary` that can be used directly whenever API request is called.

For each payload construction function, we have to check at the start of function that

```py
if object.payload:
   return object.payload
else:
   # construct the payload using other instance variables
```

```py
""" Each constructor class has payload attribute """
class X:
    """ This is a constructor class to represent X object """
    def __init__(self, payload=None):
        self.payload = payload

class Y:
    """ This is a constructor class to represent Y object """
    def __init__(self, payload=None):
        self.payload = payload

class CreatePayload:
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
    
    def create_json_for_x(self, object_x):
        if object_x.payload:
           return object_x.payload
        payload = {
                   "val" : object_x.val
                  }
        return payload

    def create_json_for_y(self, object_y):
        if object_y.payload:
           return object_y.payload
        payload = {
                     "val" : object_y.val,
                     "user" : object_y.user
                  }
        return payload

    def create_x(self, object_x):
        uri = "/test_x"
        payload = create_json_for_x(object_x)
        # send_request method sends a HTTP GET/PUT/POST/DELETE requests
        request = self.api.send_request(uri, 'post', payload)
        return request
```

I want to have a solution using `decorator` or `Metaclass` which takes the object as input and always check if it has the `payload` attribute then return the `payload` value.

Answer (score 1):

Will something like this do the job?

```
from functools import wraps
def return_payload(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        if obj.payload:
            return obj.payload
        return func(self, obj, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

class CreatePayload:
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
    
    @return_payload
    def create_json_for_x(self, object_x):
        payload = {
                   "val" : object_x.val
                  }
        return payload
```